# SQL - Search where the column has a specific value (varchar)

Tags: sql

i'm working on a personal C# app (something like a wallet) and i have a query that shows me all the expenses from all tables (sum on all int columns)

```
SELECT l.Luna, l.An, 
        sa.Salariu, sa.Bonuri, sa.Bonus,
             x.Afara, x.Vacanta, x.Cumparaturi_Diverse, x.PC,
                    z.Cumparaturi_Piata, z.FastFood, z.Mancare_Munca,
                         xa.Benzina, xa.Masina_Altele, 
                            xz.Intretinere, xz.Internet_TV, xz.Telefon, xz.Datorii,
                                 dif.Cont                           

From dbo.Luna l
INNER JOIN (SELECT Luna, AN, SUM(s.Salariu) AS Salariu, SUM(s.Bonuri) AS 

Bonuri, SUM(s.Bonus) AS Bonus FROM dbo.Salariu s GROUP BY Luna, An) sa ON l.Luna = sa.Luna and l.An = sa.An
INNER JOIN (SELECT Luna, An, SUM(a.Afara) AS Afara, SUM(a.Vacanta) AS Vacanta, SUM(a.Cumparaturi_Diverse) AS Cumparaturi_Diverse, SUM(a.PC) AS PC FROM dbo.Altele a GROUP BY Luna, AN) x ON l.Luna = x.Luna and l.An = x.An
INNER JOIN (SELECT Luna, An, SUM(m.Cumparaturi_Piata) AS Cumparaturi_Piata, SUM(m.FastFood) AS FastFood, SUM(m.Munca) AS Mancare_Munca FROM dbo.Cumparaturi m GROUP BY Luna, AN) z ON l.Luna = z.Luna and l.An = z.An
INNER JOIN (SELECT Luna, An, SUM(ma.Benzina) AS Benzina, SUM(ma.Altele) AS Masina_Altele FROM dbo.Masina ma GROUP BY Luna, AN) XA ON l.Luna = xa.Luna and l.An = xa.An
INNER JOIN (SELECT Luna, An, SUM(u.Intretinere) AS Intretinere, SUM(u.Internet_TV) AS Internet_TV, SUM(u.Telefon) AS Telefon, SUM(u.Altele) AS Datorii, SUM(u.Chirie) AS Chirie FROM dbo.Utilitati u group by Luna, AN) xz ON l.Luna = xz.Luna and l.An = xz.An
INNER JOIN dbo.Diferenta  dif ON l.Luna = dif.Luna and l.AN = dif.An
WHERE l.Luna in ('December', 'January', 'February') and l.An in (2017, 2018, 2019)
```

Thing is that in where i want to also search by a column that is available only in the tables that i have the INNER JOINS (column name = App_User).
So my question is, how can i add to this query the App_User column (which is varchar).
The where should look something like this:

```
WHERE l.Luna in ('December', 'January', 'February') and l.An in (2017, 2018, 2019) and App_User = @App_User (a parameter that will take the value from c#)
```

Comment: Which dbms?????

Comment: should this be a c# OP not sql? your sql looks fine

Comment: Well if I add App_User to where, like: WHERE l.Luna in ('December', 'January', 'February') and l.An in (2017, 2018, 2019) and App_User = @App_User , i get "Invalid column name 'App_User'" , if i want to add it in the select from the joins (since those are the tables that have the app_user column) i get "Column 'dbo.Masina.App_User' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the solution to my problem, i had to add a where clause to all inner joins WHERE s.App_User = @App_User and i also added OR ISNULL(@App_User, '') = '', if the parameter is blank it should show all data, so the query now looks like this:

```
declare @App_User varchar(255) = 'test'
SELECT DISTINCT 
        s.Luna, s.An,  
            sa.Salariu, sa.Bonuri, sa.Bonus,
                 x.Afara, x.Vacanta, x.Cumparaturi_Diverse, x.PC,
                        z.Cumparaturi_Piata, z.FastFood, z.Mancare_Munca,
                             xa.Benzina, xa.Masina_Altele, 
                                xz.Intretinere, xz.Internet_TV, xz.Telefon,
                                    lu.LunaID


From dbo.Salariu s
INNER JOIN (SELECT Luna, AN, SUM(s.Salariu) AS Salariu, SUM(s.Bonuri) AS Bonuri, SUM(s.Bonus) AS Bonus FROM dbo.Salariu s WHERE s.App_User = @App_User OR ISNULL(@App_User, '') = '' GROUP BY Luna, An) sa ON s.Luna = sa.Luna and s.An = sa.An
INNER JOIN (SELECT Luna, An, SUM(a.Afara) AS Afara, SUM(a.Vacanta) AS Vacanta, SUM(a.Cumparaturi_Diverse) AS Cumparaturi_Diverse, SUM(a.PC) AS PC FROM dbo.Altele a  WHERE a.App_User = @App_User OR ISNULL(@App_User, '') = '' GROUP BY Luna, AN) x ON s.Luna = x.Luna and s.An = x.An
INNER JOIN (SELECT Luna, An, SUM(m.Cumparaturi_Piata) AS Cumparaturi_Piata, SUM(m.FastFood) AS FastFood, SUM(m.Munca) AS Mancare_Munca FROM dbo.Cumparaturi m WHERE m.App_User = @App_User OR ISNULL(@App_User, '') = '' GROUP BY Luna, AN) z ON s.Luna = z.Luna and s.An = z.An
INNER JOIN (SELECT Luna, An, SUM(ma.Benzina) AS Benzina, SUM(ma.Altele) AS Masina_Altele FROM dbo.Masina ma WHERE ma.App_User = @App_User OR ISNULL(@App_User, '') = '' GROUP BY Luna, AN) XA ON s.Luna = xa.Luna and s.An = xa.An
INNER JOIN (SELECT Luna, An, SUM(u.Intretinere) AS Intretinere, SUM(u.Internet_TV) AS Internet_TV, SUM(u.Telefon) AS Telefon, SUM(u.Altele) AS Altele, SUM(u.Chirie) AS Chirie FROM dbo.Utilitati u WHERE u.App_User = @App_User OR ISNULL(@App_User, '') = '' GROUP BY Luna, AN) xz ON s.Luna = xz.Luna and s.An = xz.An
--INNER JOIN dbo.Diferenta  dif ON s.Luna = dif.Luna and s.AN = dif.An
INNER JOIN dbo.Luna lu on s.Luna = lu.LUNA
WHERE s.Luna in ('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'Octomber', 'December') and s.An in (2017, 2018, 2019)
ORDER BY s.An, lu.lunaID ASC
```